# matplotlib plot line and bar chart together on same x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I plot two pandas dfs together as two line charts, I get them on the same x-axis properly. When I plot one as a bar chart, however, the axis seems to be offset.

```
ax = names_df.loc[:, name].plot(color='black')
living_df.loc[:, name].plot(figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax)
```

This works properly, producing this result

[image: result]

On the other hand, this:

```
ax = names_df.loc[:, name].plot(color='black')
living_df.loc[:, name].plot.bar(figsize=(12, 8), ax=ax)
```

does not, and has this result

[image: result].

Comment: pandas bar plots are categorical. Bars are at positions 0,1,2...N-1. You can use a matplotlib bar plot to get bars at numeric positions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matplotlib` instead of calling the `plot` method of the pandas object:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Line plot
plt.plot(names_df.loc[:, name], color='black')
plt.plot(living_df.loc[:, name])
plt.show()
plt.close()

# Bar plot
plt.plot(names_df.loc[:, name].values)
bar_data = living_df.loc[:, name].values
plt.bar(range(len(bar_data)), bar_data)
plt.xticks(range(len(bar_data)), names_df.index.values)  # Restore xticks
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: I would recommend using `pandas.DataFrame.values` instead of `list()`, the `values` attribute will give the content of the `DataFrame` as a numpy array